# How to pass var on privat function Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this example code:
Why is the year not passed to the `initGridOptions` function? How to make it so that it could be seen there?

I tried to do public but it did not work.

I do not quite understand whether it is necessary to make the function `initGridOptions` privateю.

```
export class JobTimePhasingComponent implements OnInit, ComponentHasUnsavedChanges {

        public key: string = "timePhasing";
        public year: string;
        job: JobViewModel;

        constructor(
            private router: Router,
            private toastr: ToastsManager
        ) {
            this.initGridOptions();
        }

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.refresh();
        }
         private initGridOptions(): void {
        ...
                colDefs.push({
                    headerName: this.year, (UNDEFINED)
                    field: "data.Total",
                    valueGetter: cellTotalValueGetter,
                    width: 100,
                });
        }

        refresh(): void {
            let jobId = +this.route.snapshot.parent.params['id'];
            this.jobService.getJob(jobId).then(result => {
                this.fy = result.Object.FinancialYearName;
            });
        }
```

Comment: The code you posted is not sufficient. Where and how is initGridOptions called? Post a complete minimal example.

Comment: @mok i add more example code

Comment: @JBNizet i add more code

Comment: The code you posted is not valid TS: `this.year = "export class ...`? Assuming it's just `export class...`, you never initialize the year field to anything. So it's undefined. Nothing surprising.

Comment: @JBNizet ssroy, i fix.

Comment: OK, as I said in my previous comment, the year field is never initialized anywhere. So it's undefined. Visibility modifiers are completely irrelevant.

Comment: The way key is initialized , you need to initialize year as well by providing default value to that.

Comment: @TheDictator How is this best done?

Comment: `public year: string = '';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about the the accessibility of the parameter or the function, as in those cases you would get a compile error while your problem is that the parameter is displayed `undefined`.

Based on your question you can just simply initialize the variable. You can do this in the exact place that you define it:

```
year: string = ''; // or any other proper initial value
```

or perhaps in your `OnInit` and sometimes in the `constructor`, better to leave the latter only for the dependency injection, like this:

```
this.year = ''; // or any other proper initial value
```

Then you're assured that if you use this in any place after this initialization, at least it has a value.